# Repositioning (Custom) tooltips with chart.js in a Doughnut Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, chart.js

I have finally tried to rebuild my 12 month old project better.

What I Have:

- A Doughnut Chart (chart.js) with an Accordion (jqueryUI) for the details.
- When I click on a part of the doughnut, the Accordion on the left shows the Details (Text) for this Segment.

I would like to redesign the Tooltips as you can see in the both screenshots

[image: how it actualy looks like]
[image: and how it should look]

where can i change the positioning of the Tooltips to be *around* the Chart and not on it? anyone any suggestions? all i can see in the Code is just the behavior to put the arrow above or below the tooltip...

thanks for help